# Printing to the Terminal from (parallel) Threads (Common Lisp)

Tags: multithreading, printing, common-lisp

In one of Timmy Jose's blog posts at https://z0ltan.wordpress.com/2016/09/02/basic-concurrency-and-parallelism-in-common-lisp-part-3-concurrency-using-bordeaux-and-sbcl-threads/ he gives an example of the wrong way to print to the top level from inside a thread (using Bordeaux Threads as an example, although I am using Lparallel):

```
(defun print-message-top-level-wrong ()
  (bt:make-thread
    (lambda ()
      (format *standard-output* "Hello from thread!")))
  nil)

(print-message-top-level-wrong) -> NIL
```

The explanation is that "The same code would have run fine if we had not run it in a separate thread. What happens is that each thread has its own stack where the variables are rebound. In this case, even for `*standard-output*`, which being a global variable, we would assume should be available to all threads, is rebound inside each thread!"

And this is exactly what happens if the function is run in Allegro CL. However, in SBCL the function does print the intended output at the terminal. Does this mean `*standard-output*` is not being rebound in SBCL? In general, is there a cross-platform way to print to `*standard-output*` from inside a thread?

In a multithreaded situation printing to the terminal should normally be coordinated to avoid potentially printing from several streams at the same time. But there don't seem to be any functions like `atomic-format` or `atomic-print` available. Is there a straightforward way to avoid printing interference when there are multiple threads (assuming that locks/mutexes are too expensive to use for each individual printing operation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually have a *global* binding (a binding in the global environment), it *does* work for all threads; see the [documentation for bt:make-thread](https://trac.common-lisp.net/bordeaux-threads/wiki/ApiDocumentation#make-threadfunctionkeyname).  Only dynamic (re-)bindings are thread-local.  Implementations differ in how/when they bind those streams; sometimes the binding that is actually in effect for user programs is global, sometimes not.

I like to use some sort of queue or channel to coordinate output where necessary; I have not yet run into situations where the locking overhead was prohibitive.

Maybe you could try something with optimistic locking, but I don't know what has been done for that librarywise (some Lisp implementations do have CAS operations that could be used).  This should be orthogonal to the parallelism library used.

*EDIT*: Just found in the SBCL manual: [sb-concurrency](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#sb_002dconcurrency) has lock-free queues and mailboxes.

Comment: If I'm understanding, I can push the global `*standard-output*` into a lparallel queue, and then use it at any time in any thread by peeking at the queue to bind it to a thread-local variable, which appears as the stream argument in the thread's `format` statements? So even if two threads are executing `format` statements to the top level at the same time, one will wait until the other is finished?

Comment: Is it true that if all threads only read (with no writes to) a global data structure, then the read operations (without locks or atomic operations) are guaranteed safe? Eg, two `find` operations in different threads scanning the same global list at the same time for the same or different items?

Comment: Anything that just exposes *standard-output* to independent outputs of different threads will lead to interspersed output.

Comment: If you can guarantee that nothing will modify a data structure (not even under the hood, e. g. self-optimizing data structures), reading it is safe, obviously.

Comment: Can you point to an example of a Lisp op that looks like read only, but really writes under the hood? (Ps: I'm not worried about ops like `maphash` that you can use to write if you want.)

Comment: That's not Lisp specific.  Think of [splay trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree).

Comment: I think you're saying my first comment above (about passing `*standard-output*` thru a queue) will not work, because the outputs still depend on one stream. OK. But you also say "I like to use some sort of queue or channel to coordinate output...". How would this work then?

Comment: @davypough: Have a single thread for doing output, and this thread takes things to output from a queue.  In other threads, instead of writing to *standard-output*, put the things onto the queue.